# Why does stringizing an euro sign within a string literal using UTF8 not produce an UCN?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

The spec says that at phase 1 of compilation

> Any source ﬁle character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character.

And at phase 4 it says

> Preprocessing directives are executed, macro invocations are expanded

At phase 5, we have

> Each source character set member in a character literal or a string literal, as well as each escape sequence and universal-character-name in a character literal or a non-raw string literal, is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set

For the `#` operator, we have

> a `\` character is inserted before each `"` and `\` character of a character literal or string literal (including the delimiting `"` characters).

Hence I conducted the following test

```
#define GET_UCN(X) #X
GET_UCN("€")
```

With an input character set of UTF-8 (matching my file's encoding), I expected the following preprocessing result of the `#X` operation: `"\"\\u20AC\""`. GCC, Clang and boost.wave don't transform the `€` into a UCN and instead yield `"\"€\""`. I feel like I'm missing something. Can you please explain?

Comment: This would seem to be a bug in the preprocessor

Comment: Are you assuming the source character set is UTF-32? It seems like the source character set is implementation defined.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've implemented a preprocessor which gets this right: http://potswa.blogspot.com/2011/09/c11-preprocessor-in-2000-lines-of-code.html

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a bug. §2.1/1 says about Phase 1,

> (An implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual extended character encountered in the source file, and the same extended character expressed in the source file as a universal-character-name (i.e. using the \uXXXX notation), are handled equivalently.)

This is not a note or footnote. C++0x adds an exception for raw string literals, which might solve your problem at hand if you have one.

This program clearly demonstrates the malfunction:

```
#include <iostream>

#define GET_UCN(X) L ## #X

int main() {
std::wcout << GET_UCN("€") << '\n' << GET_UCN("\u20AC") << '\n';
}
```

http://ideone.com/lb9jc

Because both strings are wide, the first is required to be corrupted into several characters if the compiler fails to interpret the input multibyte sequence. In your given example, total lack of support for UTF-8 could cause the compiler to slavishly echo the sequence right through.

Comment: Uh-oh, delete a little whitespace and I invented the `###` operator…

Comment: But why does EDG/comeau, GCC, Clang and Boost.Wave all have the same bug?

Comment: @Johannes: Because it is a likely bug to occur. I suppose they all thought Phase 1 was easy enough that they could be too clever. I'm pretty surprised about Clang because its Unicode support class looked solid when I gave it a glance, a while back.

Comment: If that still isn't satisfying, note that the frontend needs a separate routine specifically for stringizing tokens into Unicode. Outside this, an implementation has no capability to generate universal-character-names. (In other words, the implementations you mentioned all omit this function.) Now, universal-character-names are totally useless to the user, stringizing is mainly used for diagnostic messages, and the main effect of fixing this bug would be to scramble `assert`-style messages for those brave programmers who actually use Unicode in identifiers.

Comment: Ah, by "stringizing tokens into Unicode" I'm also referring to the fact that most implementations are designed to work on non-Unicode systems, such as ISO 8859, so the source code could not simply be converted to hexadecimal but an actual format conversion would be required. Even if the neither the source *nor* execution character sets are Unicode. By the way, you asked for an answer on chat, don't forget to upvote…

Comment: Potatoswatter: "Now, universal-character-names are totally useless to the user" -- Not true actually. A programmer assumes that all other programmers will use the same code page, so doesn't believe that other programmers' compilers give errors about invalid multibyte characters, but they do. If all programmers would use a Greek code page and have no accented French characters, no problem. If all programmers would use UTF-8, no problem. But the fact is, different programmers use different code pages and UCNs are needed for anything outside the basic source character set.

Comment: @Windows: That's not what I meant. Take it in context — universal-character-names are useless to the user *when generated by the compiler* such as in a diagnostic message from `assert`. This is why all the compilers mentioned by Johannes *lack* the ability to generate UCNs from non-UCN source.

Answer (score -1):

"and universal-character-name in a character literal or a non-raw string literal, is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set"

used to be

"or universal-character-name in character literals and string literals is converted to a member of the execution character set"

Maybe you need a future version of g++.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where you got that citation for translation phase 1—the [C99 standard](http://code.google.com/p/yesanshare/downloads/detail?name=ISO-C-FDIS.1999-04.pdf&can=2&q=) says this about translation phase 1 in §5.1.1.2/1:

> Physical source file multibyte characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. Trigraph sequences are replaced by corresponding single-character internal representations.

So in this case, the Euro character € (represented as the multibyte sequence E2 82 AC in UTF-8) is mapped into the execution character set, which also happens to be UTF-8, so its representation remains the same.  It doesn't get converted into a universal character name because, well, there's nothing that says that it should.

Comment: There are differences between the C and C++ standard in this area.  C is designed in such a way that the original encoding can be kept, C++ assume a transformation to UCN.

Comment: What does the C99 standard have to do with anything?

Comment: Don't be too harsh on this one.  The question mentions GCC not g++.  Only one of the tags mentions c++ not c.

Answer (score -2):

I suspect you'll find that the euro sign does not satisfy the condition `Any source ﬁle character not in the basic source character set` so the rest of the text you quote doesn't apply.

Open your test file with your favourite binary editor and check what value is used to represent the euro sign in `GET_UCN("€")`

Comment: No.  The "basic source character set" is defined by the C standard to include *only* the 26 uppercase letters, 26 lowercase letters, 10 digits, 29 graphic characters, space, horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, and "some way of indicating the end of each line of text" (C99 §5.2.1).

Comment: @adam sorry I expressed myself clumsily.  I was talking about what the compiler Johanes is using is actually doing, not about what the standard says it should be doing.  Still, I did say "I suspect".  If there's a standard compliant explaination for what Johannes is seeing I'll happily acknowledge my suspicion is wrong.