# What characters are left for pp-tokens?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, language-lawyer

The spec lists the categories of pp tokens at 2.5, but contains a last category

> each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above

I have a hard time finding an example where a pp token capturing such a character yields a valid C++ program. As 2.5 explains, a program may contain a wild `"` or `'` token, but then behavior is undefined. Is there any example of a valid program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stringize a stray token into validity. Actually; you already did just that in [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463014/why-does-stringizing-an-euro-sign-within-a-string-literal-using-utf8-not-produce)!

Stray character tokens may also appear in a group skipped by conditional compilation, i.e.

```
#if 0
@ \ ` €
#endif
```

Note that in all these cases, the only stray character token is the backslash, since a UCN such as `\u0040` does not form an identifier, and UCN is a special case within identifiers, and the backslash alone is "the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token," with `u0040` being a separate identifier.

Comment: Hm only the \ character of those stray tokens match the last pp token category though, because that's the only character in that line that's in the basic source character set. The others will become UCN's (identifiers), or am I missing something? I'm accepting this because of the `#if 0` idea and the stringize / concatenate idea. Thanks!

Comment: Only certain UCNs may form identifiers (§E). Technically, I think that the three extended characters would form a stray backslash followed by an alphanumeric sequence which becomes an identifier. This is due to the explicit maximum munch rule. (Actually, that implies that diacritical marks *cannot* be catenated, because only the leading backslash is seen by the `##` operator!)

Comment: "may" or "can"? If it is "may", then according to the IEC directives, the invalid sequence of characters must still be lexed as an identifier, and rejected as invalid later on.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb confused, see chat

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `$` and `@`, for example, fall into that category (assuming these characters are in the source character set).  Both are valid pp-tokens, but are not valid tokens, and will be diagnosed as a syntax error in a later translation phase (unless they've been removed by `#if`, `#ifdef`, etc.).

I don't know of any case where such a pp-token results in a valid token.

Comment: Hm, `$` and `@` are not in the basic source character set. So both would be translated to universal character names and would be handled by the other pp token categories (identifier).

Comment: Maybe a '#' that is not at the beginning of a line? Or a '\' that is not at the end of a line nor inside of a literal?

Comment: @rod a `#` is a preprocessing-op-or-punc. A \ that is not at the end of a line nor inside of a literal seems to be possible. Having `#define BAR(X) #X` then one can say `BAR(A\nB)`, which contains identifiers `A` and `nB` separated by the \ token, matched by the last PP token category (or if the implementation allows identifiers containing \, the it would be a single identifier). Thanks for this insight!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Not all universal character names may appear in identifiers; see N3290 2.11p1, which refers to E.1.  (I haven't taken the time to decode what E.1 says.)

Comment: @Keith yeah but the characters that are not in the basic source character set are all replaced to universal character names. Later those that are disallowed in an identifier may be rejected.

Comment: Does `"` need to be always interpreted as "non-terminated string literal" rather than "non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above"?

Comment: Re: "are valid pp-tokens, but are not valid tokens": FYI: `0xe+1` is valid pp-token, but invalid token. GCC/Clang/ICC diagnose it, MSVC doesn't.